# Bounded density implies bounded MGF?

Tags: probability-theory

If $X$ is a continuously distributed random variable, with density bounded above by 1, is it true that $\mathbf{E}(\exp(-tX)) \leq 1/t$ for all $t > 0$?

Comment: Have you tried writing down the integral for that expectation?  If you apply the only fact you know ($\lvert f(x)\rvert\leq 1$), this result is immediate (if you assume $X$ is non-negative)

Comment: Don't you need that $P(X<0)=0$ for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $X$ only has positive support, I think the intended argument is
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-tX}\right]
 = \int_0^\infty e^{-tx} f(x) dx
 \le \int_0^\infty e^{-tx} dx
 = \left. \frac{-1}{te^{tx}} \right|_0^\infty
 = \frac{1}{t}.
$$

Comment: Yes, this is helpful. In my problem, I can assume positive support.